# How to model the double jump in Super Mario using projectile motion

Tags: models, motion, projectile

So the single jump in Super mario games follows a curved trajectory of the formula s = s0 + v0t + ½ at2. The double jump in mario consists of two different parabolas combined. I know that the max height of the first jump is the beginning of the second jump and the gravity doubles by the end of the second jump making a faster landing than the first. Would it be a piece-wise function or how would it work?

*Could anyone guide me through/ explain what equation would that result in? Any help would be very much appreciated!

If anyone needs me to explain more, please let me know.

Here is a link to explain my question https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1096&v=hG9SzQxaCm8&feature=emb_title

@ 17:58

I would be very grateful for any help :) Even if it is only ideas, thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do a double jump as a single function? Even if you are using function for the motion in the game, you would change the motion function the moment the player hits jump the second time, so the formula is another function of the same form.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks so much for pointing that out! I really appreciate your help